# Python CSV reader doesn´t work

Tags: python-2.7, csv, module

this is my first post here. I have this problem I try to run this code and I get this error.. Can you tell me why? my python version is 2.7

```
from csv import reader
def load_csv(filename):
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    lines = reader(file)
    dataset = list(lines)
    return dataset
filename = 'pima-indians-diabetes.csv'
dataset = load_csv(filename)
print('loaded data set tatata').format(filename, len(dataset), len(dataset[0]))
```

error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name reader
```

I can't find the problem. I tryed to download a new csv module, but something doesn't work with the file from [CSV module for Python](http://www.object-craft.com.au/projects/csv/download.html)

Comment: I bet you called your file `csv.py` right?

Comment: Try `import os,csv;print(os.path.abspath(csv.__file__))`. Is python's csv or your own?